# Blender: UV Mapping - Texture warping slightly, strange looking UV Map on one of the faces

Tags: textures, blender, uv-mapping

So I am quite new to the Blender scene and especially new to UV mapping, so please consider this when answering.

I am trying to apply a wooden plank texture onto a simple mesh of a plank that has a chip in either of the smaller sides of the rectangular mesh.

When I create this, the top face of the plank has a diagonal warped line going from one side of the plank to the other side. I think this may be because the face of the top of the plank does not look like it does in the 3D view for some reason.

The link below is an image of the 3D view showing the top of the plank that has the warping line alongside the Node view and the UV view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxa8y.png

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include relevant code, including what you've tried, so that folks can help to guide you.

Comment: Hi Jason, this is not a programming question -- you would be better off asking on https://blender.stackexchange.com/